# $(x+y)^{p/2} \leq x^{p/2} + y^{p/2} (1<p<2)?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Let $x, y \in (0, \infty)$ and $1<p<2.$

**My Question**: Is it true that, $$(x+y)^{p/2} \leq x^{p/2} + y^{p/2}  ?$$

Comment: @OBDA; If we take, $p=2,$ then $(x+y)^{p}\leq x^{p} + y^{p};$ may not be true!

Comment: Related: [Prove variant of triangle inequality containing p-th power for 0 < p < 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80003/prove-variant-of-triangle-inequality-containing-p-th-power-for-0-p-1). You are basically asking whether the function $x\mapsto x^p$ is [subadditive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity).

Answer (score 1):

Define $f(x)=(x+1)^{\frac{p}{2}}-x^{\frac{p}{2}}-1$, $x>0$. Note that, $f'(x)=\frac{p}{2}\left((x+1)^{\frac{p-2}{2}}-x^{\frac{p-2}{2}}\right)\le0$, because $x+1\ge x$ and $\frac{p-2}{2}<0.$ So, for $x>0$, $f$ is decreasing, then $f(x)\le f(0)$ for $x>0$. Therefore, 
$$(x+1)^{\frac{p}{2}}\le x^{\frac{p}{2}}+1.$$
Replace $x$ for $\frac{x}{y}$, $x,y>0$, we obtain,
$$\left(\frac{x}{y}+1\right)^{\frac{p}{2}}\le \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{\frac{p}{2}}+1.$$
Therefore,
$$\left(x+y\right)^{\frac{p}{2}}\le x^{\frac{p}{2}}+y^{\frac{p}{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Divide both sides by $(x+y)^{p/2}$ to get 
$$1 \le (\frac{x}{x+y})^{p/2}+(\frac{y}{x+y})^{p/2}$$

Since $x,y>0$ then $t=\frac{x}{x+y}$ and $1-t=\frac{y}{x+y}$ are in the interwal $(0,1)$.

So let us consider the function $f(t)=t^{q}+(1- t)^q$ for $q\in (1/2, 1)$ and $t \in [0,1]$.

$f'(t)=qt^{q-1}-q(1-t)^{q-1}=q(t^{q-1}-(1-t)^{q-1})=0.$

Let me continue:

$f'(t)=0 \Leftrightarrow t^{q-1}-(1-t)^{q-1}=0 \Leftrightarrow t^{q-1}=(1-t)^{q-1} \Leftrightarrow t=1-t$. Therefore $t=1/2.$

For $t \in (0,1/2),  t^{q-1}>(1-t)^{q-1} \Rightarrow f'(t)>0$.

For $t \in (1/2,1),  t^{q-1}<(1-t)^{q-1} \Rightarrow f'(t)<0$.

Therefore the smallest value of $f(t)$ either $f(0)=1$ or $f(1)=1$.

Hence $f(t) \ge 1$  for $t \in [0,1]$. This completes the proof.

Comment: The positive square root of 1/4 (case $p =1$) is 1/2.

Comment: Why can't two fractions, each less than 1, sum to more than 1? Your argument is incomplete.

Comment: Yes, I am not right. Sorry!

Comment: @kmitov; thanks; would you please tell me where we are getting contradiction ?