# How do I show that $a^p + b^p > (a + b)^p$ for $a,b>0$ and $0<p<1$?

Tags: inequality

A question on my math homework asks us to show that if $0 < p < 1$ and $a, b > 0$, then $a^p + b^p > (a + b)^p$. I have no idea how to do this, any pointers?

Comment: See also:
[Prove that $(p+q)^m \leq p^m+q^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264156),
[Prove variant of triangle inequality containing p-th power for 0 < p < 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80003),
[Does $|x|^p$ with $0<p<1$ satisfy the triangle inequality on $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134714)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1707969/9464

Comment: How does a homework problem void of any trace whatsoever wrt effort, get three upvotes?  I'm willing to bet they all come from answerers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $$t=\frac a{a+b},$$
you can rewrite $$t^p+(1-t)^p>1,$$
with $0<t,1-t<1$.

For $0<p<1$,

$$t^p>t\text{, and }(1-t)^p>1-t.$$
By summing you get the desired result.

Comment: Is it linked to convexity ?

Comment: @Maman: yep, all the involved functions are convex.

Answer (score 10):

First, the inequality is homogeneous, so you can divide both $a$ and $b$ by $a+b$, then you have to show that
$$x^p+y^p>1$$
if $x+y=1$, $x,y>0$ and $0<p<1$. But now, $x,y<1$ so $x^p>x$ and $y^p>y$ for $0<p<1$. And you are done.

Answer (score 6):

Fix $a\gt 0$, and consider $f(x)=a^p+x^p-(a+x)^p$. Note that $f(0)=0$. We have $f'(x)=x^{p-1}-(a+x)^{p-1}$. Since $p-1\lt 0$, we have $f'(x)\gt 0$ whenever $x\gt 0$. So $f(x)$ is increasing, and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

If you where to expand, you would get;
$$
(a+b)^{p} = a^{p} + b^{p} + C
$$
Where C would become a positive amount that depends on a,b and p.

*(If you want to know what that would be, I suggest you google binomial theory and Pascal's triangle)*

Comment: But $p\in(0,1)$, how do you use the binomial theorem when $p$ isn't a natural number?

Comment: At least, when $p$ is the inverse of an integer, you can expand $(a^p+b^p)^{1/p}$. I guess this could be extended to rationals.