# Is the operator $(\cdot)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ subadditive for $1<p<\infty$ for positive numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Is the operator $(\cdot)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ subadditive for $1<p<\infty$?

I am aware that the square root operator is subadditive for positive numbers, as for $a,b > 0$:

$\sqrt{a+b}\leq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\iff a+b\leq a+2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}+b$

and the last statement is trivially true since $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}\geq 0$.

How can I generalize this proof for $p\in (1,\infty)$?

Is the assumption on non-negativity of $a$ and $b$ necessary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show that $(a+b)^p\leq a^p + b^p$ for $a,b\geqslant 0$ and $0<p<1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707969/how-to-show-that-abp-leq-ap-bp-for-a-b-geqslant-0-and-0p1)

Comment: The problem with negative $a, b$ is how to *define* $a^{1/p}$ etc.

Comment: More generally: [Concave implies subadditive](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295551/42969).